# Calculate the sum of minutes between statuses Clickhouse

Tags: gaps-and-islands, clickhouse

There is a table in ClickHouse that is constantly updated, format:

```
date_time           | shop_id | item_id | status | balance
---------------------------------------------------------------
2022-09-09 13:00:01 | abc     | 1234    | 0      | 0
2022-09-09 13:00:00 | abc     | 1234    | 1      | 3
2022-09-09 12:50:00 | abc     | 1234    | 1      | 10
```

The table stores statuses and balances for each item_id, when the balance is changed, a new record with status, time and balance is added. If the balance is = 0, the status changes to 0.

Need to calculate how much time (how many minutes) every item_id in the shop was available for the day. The status may change several times a day.

Please help me calculate this.

Comment: Looks like a variation of the "gaps and islands" problem. What have you tried thus far?

Comment: I tried `LEAD(date_time) - date_time` in CTE, but it seems to be wrong.

Comment: Hi and welcome to dba.se! Would I be correct in assuming that `balance = 0` means that the item is unavailable?

Comment: @Vérace Hi! Yes, you're right